# Not able to connect to eclipse marketplace Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-oxygen

I have eclipse Oxygen installed and am trying to connect to Eclipse marketplace, to install plugin, it gives below exception -
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException
[image]

Comment: Have you done what it said to do?

Comment: @nitind Yes I did verified my internet connection.

Comment: FYI- I tried with -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true as suggest somewhere at bugs.eclipse.org , but that also did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually after setting Active Provider to "Native" I could get rid of the issue in question.

Go to :
`Eclipse (Window-->Preferences-->General-->Network Connections)`

Select Active Provider as Native from drop down and apply.
Restart eclipse and try the :

Help-->Eclipse Marketplace.. option again.

Comment: In my case I actually had to change from Native to Direct to bypass a proxy that wasn't working. But after that restarting Eclipse did work.